# Cannot select option in select tag

Tags: javascript

I have problem with selecting options in select tag. The list that i get in the dropdown contains 3 objects. The problem is whichever option i select , it always auto selects the first one.

```
 fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        data.forEach((item) => {
          options.push({
            v: item.name,
            t: item.name,
          });
        });
        console.log(options);
        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          let value = options[i].v;
          let text = options[i].t;
          $("#node-input-options").append(
            $("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(text) //For every element in the select tag append appropriate value and text (   <option value="#">#</option>    )
          );
        }
      });
  };
  fetchURL();
```

Comment: Can we have output of `options`? so we can create a snippet?

Comment: Seems something related to API response. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfb27301/) I only test the second part with static options and all seems to work correctly.

Comment: options output is `[{v:pump1,t:pump1}, {v:pump2, t: pump2}]` I have other dropdowns filled the same way and it works fine . Only with this i get this weird error

Comment: @SimoneRossaini

Comment: As @DavideBrognoli said all work with static code. do you see if you have any error into `console.log`?

Comment: nope no errors. The problem is that if i select option 2 - The value will be from option2 but the option displayed will be option1. If u dont understand ill send u 2 pictures